# Why the variable is not being updated inside the for loop?

Tags: go, variables, scope

I am having an issue that I do not understand, there is a variable in the func main that is not being update inside a for loop, I really dont get why the variable is not receiving the new value. This is a coding game exercise. Each time the inner loop finishes I have to get the highest mountain and then shoot it, the logic that I implemented is good but I only need the vatiable shoot to be update so the mountains will be shoot at each iteration but I always receive the initial value 0 instead. Note that I am not looking for the answer of the exercise but the resolution of the issue.
Here the game -> https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/the-descent

Here the code:

```
    func main() {
    shoot := 0   //this is the variable I want to be updated
    higherMountainH := 0
    for {

        for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {

            var mountainH int  // This variable is updated in each iteration by game giving the hight of the mountain so it always returns a variable from 9 to 2

            if mountainH > higherMountainH { //mountainH is never 0 because the game engine gives to it the corresponding value in each iteration
                higherMountainH = mountainH
                shoot = i   //Here is where it is supposed to be updated
            }

            fmt.Scan(&mountainH)
        }
        
        fmt.Println(shoot)  //here always receive 0
        higherMountainH = 0  
        shoot = 0
    }
 }
```

Comment: It never goes into the if statement, because mountainH is 0

Comment: You're only scanning into `mountainH` after the (inner) loop but never use the scanned value. Then next iteration begins and `mountainH` is again `0`.

Comment: In the game mountainH receives a value that is the height of the mountain, in the if I want to update the variable to get the heightest mountain

Comment: mountainH is updated in each iteration giving the height of one mountain.

Comment: Thank you icza your solution was the one that help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `mountainH` is overwritten at every iteration:

```
for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
    // Here mountainH is created and is set to 0 at every iteration.
    var mountainH int
    // So the condition is always false.
    if mountainH > higherMountainH {
        higherMountainH = mountainH
        shoot = i
    }
    // mountainH is read after the condition is checked.
    fmt.Scan(&mountainH)
}
```

Fixed version:

```
// If you define the variable outside of the loop it won't be 
// overwritten at every iteration.
var mountainH int
for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
    if mountainH > higherMountainH {
        higherMountainH = mountainH
        shoot = i
    }
    fmt.Scan(&mountainH)
}
```

Comment: Actually the variable mountainH receives his value from the game in every iteration, cause I could do the exercise in python using the same logic in the code above, besides that the game explains that mountainH has a value which is the height of the mountain.